# смешивание нот python

Tags: python

```
from music21 import note, stream
s = stream.Stream()
s.append(note.Note(0))
s.append(note.Note(56))
s.write('midi', fp='test.midi')
```

в файл test.midi записались два звука, которые воспроизводятся поочерёдно.
проблема: надо, чтобы эти два звука прозвучали одновременно и записались в файл. как это сделать? напишите код для этого, пожалуйста
P.S: можно использовать другие библиотеки для работы со звуком))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одновременное звучание двух и более нот - это аккорд, и про них [есть отдельная глава в документации](https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/usersGuide/usersGuide_07_chords.html).

Добавление аккорда будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
from music21 import note, stream, chord
s = stream.Stream()
c = chord.Chord([note.Note(0), note.Note(56)])
s.append(c)
s.write('midi', fp='test.midi')
```

Comment: спасибо большое! :)